# Ajax event after an ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I have an ajax event that shows me a table this table I would like to display it in datatables so with ajax ,the two call of ajax are in the same page, and the table is in filtre.php ,here is my code :

```
$('#form').on('submit',function(){        
           var date= $('#date').val();
           var fact= $('#fact').val();    
           var matr= $('#matr').val(); 
           var type= $('#type').val(); 
           var dest= $('#dest').val(); 
           $.ajax({    
              url:"filtre.php",
              method:"post",
              data:{date:date,fact:fact,matr:matr,type:type,dest:dest},
              dataType: "html",
              success:function(data)
               {       
                $('#result').html(data);                  
               }
            });  
            return false;
     });


$('#mytable').DataTable({
           responsive: true,
           searching: false,
           aoColumnDefs: [
                {"aTargets": [0], "bSortable": true},
                {"aTargets": [2], "asSorting": ["asc"], "bSortable": true},
            ],
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
            }
    };
```

Comment: thanks guys, i solved the problem, i just forget <thead> and <tbody> in my table.

Answer (score 0):

Write the datatable triggering event within  a function and call that function within ajax success.

```
function myDataTable(){
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
       "responsive": true,
       "searching": false,
       "aoColumnDefs": [
            {"aTargets": [0], "bSortable": true},
            {"aTargets": [2], "asSorting": ["asc"], "bSortable": true},
        ],
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
        }
    });
}


 $('#form').on('submit',function(){        
       var date= $('#date').val();
       var fact= $('#fact').val();    
       var matr= $('#matr').val(); 
       var type= $('#type').val(); 
       var dest= $('#dest').val(); 
       $.ajax({    
          url:"filtre.php",
          method:"post",
          data:{date:date,fact:fact,matr:matr,type:type,dest:dest},
          dataType: "html",
          success:function(data)
           {       
            $('#result').html(data);
            myDataTable();                  
           }
        });  
        return false;
 });
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I do not know it does not work

Comment: @hananeazee, can you please explain your need clearly.

Comment: your code RAMYA give me this error in consol google: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous>

Comment: @hananeazee, I just edited my code. can you please try now.

Comment: i don't know what did you changed in the code ,but i have the same error in console google.

Comment: just added the double quotes datatable attribute

Comment: ok thnx for your help ,  i solved the problem, i just forget <thead> and <tbody> in my table.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is missing a "**)**" at the end. See below;

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
           responsive: true,
           searching: false,
           aoColumnDefs: [
                {"aTargets": [0], "bSortable": true},
                {"aTargets": [2], "asSorting": ["asc"], "bSortable": true},
            ],
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
            }
    } /*Here->*/ );
```

You did not give any details regarding where you call the `DataTable` function but you can simply put the construction function

```
$('#mytable').DataTable();
```

right after

```
$('#result').html(data);
```

in your ajax call; assuming the `id` attribute of your `table` is `mytable` such as `<table id="mytable"></table>`.

Comment: that's exactly what I did

Answer (score 0):

Try with this solution, Hope it help:

```
 $('#form').on('submit',function(){        
               var date= $('#date').val();
               var fact= $('#fact').val();    
               var matr= $('#matr').val(); 
               var type= $('#type').val(); 
               var dest= $('#dest').val(); 
               $.ajax({    
                  url:"filtre.php",
                  method:"post",
                  data:{date:date,fact:fact,matr:matr,type:type,dest:dest},
                  dataType: "html",
                  success:function(data)
                   {       
                    $('#result').html(data);   
                   $('#mytable').DataTable().destroy(); // destroy datatable if already exist.
                   initDataTable();               
                   }
                });  
                return false;
         });



$(document).ready(function () {
    initDataTable(); // initialize datatable on PageLoad
});
 function initDataTable() {

     $('#mytable').DataTable({
               responsive: true,
               searching: false,
               aoColumnDefs: [
                    {"aTargets": [0], "bSortable": true},
                    {"aTargets": [2], "asSorting": ["asc"], "bSortable": true},
                ],
                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
                }
        };
}
```